# Problem with `longtabu` package not doing pagebreak

Tags: tables, page-breaking, longtable

I wanted to insert some text in my `longtabu` table and was surprised that I don't get a pagebreak and the whole text is on the second page. The table doesn't even break the page on the second page. Here is my MWE:

```
\documentclass[pdftex, 12pt, oneside]{book}

\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\usepackage[scaled]{helvet}
    \renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{tabu}
\usepackage[paper = a4paper, margin = 1in]{geometry}

\begin{document}
  \begin{onehalfspace}
    Some text above:\\
    \lipsum[1]
    \begin{longtabu} to \linewidth {| X |}
      \hline
      \bfseries{Example table}\\
      \hline
      \endhead
      \lipsum[2-7] \\
      \hline        
    \end{longtabu}
  \end{onehalfspace}
\end{document}
```

Am I missing something?

Comment: A row can't be broken across pages. Break will occur only between rows.

Comment: For real? I always thought that's what it is there for. -.- Is there any other way how I could achieve a pagebreak in a row?

Comment: @Chris.V breaking within a row would be really hard to specify (even if it didn't require re-writing most of longtable) consider that the cells may have text of different baselines, or images or nested tables, and you'd have to find a consistent place to break each column. If your real example is just one column then you don't need a table at all of course, and many examples of 2-column tables can better be set as a list.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Yeah I already guessed that it would be hard to achieve and I think I will convert this one-column-table into normal text. I hope that I don't need any many-column-table in my term paper. :)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Mind writing an answer?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Breaking within a row would be really hard to specify (even if it didn't require re-writing most of `longtable`) consider that the cells may have text of different baselines, or images or nested tables, and you'd have to find a consistent place to break each column.

If your real example is just one column then you don't need a table at all of course, and many examples of 2-column tables can better be set as a list, see the answer below for some thoughts on switching from table to list layout.

[parameter description with long descriptions and long lists -- possibility of page break?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/135333/parameter-description-with-long-descriptions-and-long-lists-possibility-of-pa)