# parameter description with long descriptions and long lists -- possibility of page break?

Tags: tables, lists, page-breaking

I have a series of equations with following parameter description. Some of those descriptions are relatively long, meaning that I nead a line break. I use so far table, and to accomodate the long lines I use tabularx

```
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{}lX}
where: & $a$ -- long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text ,\\
 & $b$ -- long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text ,\\
 & $c$ -- text,\\
 & $d$ -- text, and\\
 & $e$ -- text.
\end{tabularx}
```

As the list is relatively long and there are several such equations with list, this leads to ugly spacing between parameters. I would therefore like to allow page breakes within the table. I found the possibility of using `ltxtable` and `longtable`, but don't really understand how it would need to be implemented. Is a table even the best solution or are there other and better option where I can have long descriptions and long lists with page breaks?

Comment: It's a list so you could use a list not a table, then it will break over the page

Comment: you mean like `\begin{description}[noitemsep,nolistsep] \item a -- basfas \item b -- asfasf \end{descriptions}` but then for long lines the second line is indented and how to put the "where" on the first line?

Comment: Yes but latex lists have many parameters that can control the layout, see the `enumitem` package, (I don't have time for a full answer today as I'm in a meeting, but someone could provide one:-)

Comment: I see that a similar problem was posed in this [question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/95838/how-to-write-a-perfect-equation-parameters-description). However I think most of them (?) will have the problem of no page break.

Comment: Yes the question there is essentially a duplicate I suppose I should move my answer there and then close this. Of the answers there the ones based on ams alignments or tabbing will (or can) break over a page (`\allowdisplaybreaks` for ams alignments) however a list is more flexible and I claim conceptually the right thing

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Something like this, but modify parameters to suit (or use the `enumitem` interface)

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\setlength\textwidth{10cm}

\newenvironment{plist}{%
\list{}{\labelwidth0pt
\def\makelabel##1{\makebox[2cm][r]{##1 -- }}%
\itemsep 0pt
\advance\leftmargin2cm
\itemindent-2cm
}}
{\endlist}

\begin{document}

\noindent X\dotfill X
\begin{plist}
\item[where\hfill $a$]
long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text,
long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text,
\item[$b$]long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text,
\item[$c$]text,
\item[$d$]text, and
\item[$e$]text.
\end{plist}

\end{document}
```

---

or

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\setlength\textwidth{10cm}

\newenvironment{plist}{%
\list{}{\labelwidth0pt
\def\makelabel##1{\makebox[1.5cm][r]{##1}}%
\parsep 0pt
\itemsep 0pt
\advance\leftmargin1.5cm
\itemindent-1.5cm
}}
{\endlist}

\begin{document}

\noindent X\dotfill X
\begin{plist}
\item[where\hfill $a$]--
long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text,
long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text,
\item[$b$]-- long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text,
\item[$c$]-- text,
\item[$d$]-- text, and
\item[$e$]-- text.
\item[$C_{ox}$]${}=23$nF -- gate capacitance,
\item[$\mu$]-- mobility in the semiconductor [cm$^2$/Vs], and
\item[$V_{g,th}$]-- threshold voltage.
\end{plist}

\end{document}
```

---

or (one *last* time:-) another variant (in this one I made the indent an optional parameter to the environment, defaulting to 1.5cmand as requested set `where` flush left.):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\setlength\textwidth{10cm}

\newenvironment{plist}[1][1.5cm]{%
\list{}{
\def\makelabel##1{##1\hfill}%
\parsep 0pt
\itemsep 0pt
\labelsep0pt
\labelwidth#1\relax
\leftmargin\labelwidth
\itemindent0pt
}}
{\endlist}

\begin{document}

\noindent X\dotfill X
\begin{plist}
\item[where] $a$ --
long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text,
long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text,
\item $b$ -- long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text,
\item $c$ -- text,
\item $d$ -- text, and
\item $e$ -- text.
\item $C_{ox}=23$nF -- gate capacitance,
\item $\mu$ -- mobility in the semiconductor [cm$^2$/Vs], and
\item $V_{g,th}$ -- threshold voltage.
\end{plist}

\end{document}
```

Comment: This goes in the right direction. However I don't like the large spacing between items. I should just be normal spacing as in text. I have some times longer items where I put e.g. `$a$=1213424 units` which would mean that I would have to implement a larger indent. Also it would look then a bit shaky on the left. I care more about alignement for $a$, $b$ etc than of the definitions

Comment: the vertical separation between items is of course setable in the list definition (`\parsep 0pt` probably does what you want there) as for the long items you would need to give more complete example, the original code use a tabular `l` so everything would indent to the widest here you would have to manually adjust the `2cm` as written but you could set that to set it from the widest entry (as \bibitem` does)

Comment: I have for example `\begin{tabular}{@{}ll}
  where: & $C_{ox}=23$nF -- gate capacitance,\  & $\mu$ -- mobility in the semiconductor [cm$^2$/Vs], and\  & $V_{g,th}$ -- threshold voltage.\\end{tabular}`

Comment: @user2758804 added 2nd version perhaps closer to what you mean but basically you can adjust the list parameters in lots of ways...

Comment: So what if I just take `\item[where] $a$ -- asjfalsjf  \item $b$ -- asdfasd` but then how to align the "where" to the left, as for a text (no indent)? Changing the makelabel to `\def\makelabel##1{\makebox[1.5cm][l]{##1}}%` seems not sufficient

Comment: I found something with the option labelwidth, but also then I don't manage to get the alignment of the labels at the left, as in block text

Comment: I like the solution, however is there a possibility to get the "where" aligned tot he left?

Comment: @user2758804  updated as requested...

Comment: Perfect, thanks a lot. If you have time, can you tell me the meaning/syntax of `[1][1.5cm]`, `\def\makelabel##1{##1\hfill}%`and `\labelwidth#1\relax` so that for a next time I might find the answer more easily my self? (I didn't find any good documentations)

Comment: `#1` is the optional argument to plist so try `\begin{plist}[5in]`  If you don't specify it it uses the given default of 1.5cm. `\labelwidth#1\relax` is just primitive syntax for `\setlength\labelwidth{#1}`